# Shared memory in C++ crash

Tags: c++, posix, shared-memory

I am using a shared memory for storing some data using the `shmget` function. Then I use `shmat` to attach it and save data. The next time i attach it, the program crashes. What are the possibilities that this line:

```
if((smemPtr = (int*)shmat(sMemId,NULL,0)) != (int *) -1)
```

crashes? I need to know the scenarios under which this line crashes. The `sMemId` has a value.

Comment: Why don't you build a debug build, and look at it in gdb?

Comment: Are you sure it's that line that causes the crash ?

Comment: @elmo shmat() returns (void *)-1 when it fails, so because the result's being cast to int * here it kind of makes sense. I'm not convinced it'd actually return the same value though - certainly not on all platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(int*) (...) != (int *) -1
```

Pointer to another object is unsigned value. In this code i see C-style casting signed (negative) value to unsigned. Result is depend from compiler, platform, and in the general case -- undefined.